# Is it possible to connect Mongdb offline for testing and mocking?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

As the title, probably a dumb question again, is it possible to connect Mongodb locally?

If yes, would you tell me what to do?

I tried to use Mongo Compass but in vain, it said 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017'.

I just want to test my app wherever I am, sometimes isn't able to connect wifi....

Comment: Yes, by running MongoDB locally.

Comment: Make sure that mongod service is running on that port

Answer (score 0):

Where is your mongodb instance running?

- If your instance is on a distant server then the answer is NO.
- If your instance is installed locally on your computer or running on a local docker container then the answer is YES. I guess you'll have to adapt your connection string according to your setup.

Quoting the documentation:

> If your MongoDB Server is running locally, you can use the connection string "mongodb://localhost:`port`" where `port` is the port number you configured your server to listen for incoming connections.

You can read here:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/connection/